# Preservation of coequalizers of $F$-split pairs

Tags: category-theory

The condition "$F$ preserves coequalizers of $F$-split pairs" is a condition that appears in monadicity theorems.

What kind of colimits is it sufficient for $F$ to preserve so that it preserves coequalizers of $F$-split pairs? Is it enough for $F$ to preserve coequalizers of split pairs? But then, aren't those always preserved, by any functor? I am a bit confused. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is a split pair? A pair having a split coequalizer?

Comment: Yes: a pair $(f,g)$ in $\text{dom}F$ for which $(Ff,Fg)$ has a split coequalizer in $\text{codom} F$.

Comment: It suffices to preserve coequalizers. This is sometimes too strong. A better condition is that it's sufficient to preserve reflexive coequalizers.

Answer (score 1):

Any functor preserves coequalizers of contractible pairs, also known as *split coequalizers*; so this condition is not sufficient. The point is that an $F$-split pair is not necessarily contractible itself, it only becomes one after applying  $F$. So its coequalizer is not necessarily an absolute colimit.

Of course, if $F$ preserves colimits or simply coequalizers, then it will preserve coequalizers of $F$-split pairs, but other than that I don't think there is any nice property that implies preservation of these coequalizers.

**Remark :** My answer is only about the condition of preservation of coequalizers of $F$-split pairs, separately from the existence of a left adjoint and conservativeness. As others have pointed out, there are some variants of the monadicity theorem with other conditions, but this only applies if the other conditions are satisfied.

Comment: The [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadicity+theorem) includes a variety of sufficient conditions for monadicity. For example, the crude monadicity theorem states that a conservative right adjoint is monadic if (but not only if) the domain has and the functor preserves reflexive pairs. Similarly, between finitely complete categories, it is sufficient to create quotients of congruences.